# Can a Notepad++ User-Defined Language be defined that provides Workflowy functionality?

Tags: notepad++, bulletedlist

I'd like to create a UDL in Notepad++ that provides a decent version of Workflowy's fractal organization pattern. That would look like many possible indent levels of bulleted lists and the ability to collapse (or roll up) at any level. The problem is, the UDL definition process is non-obvious.

For those of you not familiar with Workflowy, here's a screen capture.[image: Workflowy image from https://www.geekwire.com/2018/workflowly-founder-new-list-update-popular-app-keeping-purists-happy/]